# C# Base64 Encode and Decode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, base64, urlencode

Lessons Learned:

1. If you want to pass VALUES to a Controller, and those values have special characters Use the Built in Url.Action Function, instead of trying to manually Base64 the information.
2. When Creating a URL using Url Action. There are several Gotchyas that you have to worry about.

- The Controller is the second parameter, but make sure you don't put the "Controller" name in the class. IE: My class is called PivotSearchController, but I need to provide the "PivotSearch" string in the second paramaeter.
- ```
                     <a href=@Url.Action("pivotSearch", "PivotSearch", new {
                                                             key= @PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString(),
                                                             value = @content
                                            })>  @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(content.Trim().ToLower()).Truncate(70)
  ```

  ```
                                                         <a href=@Url.Action("pivotSearch", "PivotSearch", new {
                                                             key= @PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString(),
                                                             value = @content
                                            })>  @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(content.Trim().ToLower()).Truncate(70)
  ```

TLDR:
Question: The quick Question: How do I ENCODE and DECODE raw data (of any type) and place it within a named route?! The method I leveraged seems to fail due to the following Exception:  **"System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string**" Certain types of data are sent when a decode happens.  Please keep in mind the data that could be sent can contain any random character and special characters.

Question: The quick Question: How do I ENCODE and DECODE raw-data (of any type) and place it within a named route?!

```
Exception: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 characters, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

1. I have a Dotnet Core Rest API Endpoint that Matches this format.

   ```
    [Route("/ipaddress/pivotSearch/{key}/{value}/{incomingPage?}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> pivotSearch(string key, string value, int page = 1){}
   ```
2. Passing Base64 via request is not possible due to special characters such as the / interfering with the route. Therefore, in addition to Base64, I also escape special characters via DataEscapeString.
3. I created a simple Encode and Decode Function using StackOverflow, which I use in my controller.

   ```
   public static string SmartEncode(this string value)
   {
       string convertToBase64String = @Convert.ToBase64String(@Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
       return Uri.EscapeDataString(convertToBase64String);

       //return @HttpUtility.UrlEncode(convertToBase64String);
       }

   public static string SmartDecode(this string value)
   {
       try
       {
           Log.Information($"Initial String To Decode: {value}");
           var decodeUrlString = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value.Trim()); ;

           Log.Information($"UrlDecode String: {decodeUrlString}");
           Log.Information($"UrlDecode String: #{decodeUrlString.Length}");

           return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(decodeUrlString.Trim() + "="));
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value.Trim()));
       }
   }
   ```
4. When My controller is hit. I get this Error:
   PGh0dHBzOi8vY3NlLmVuZ2luLnVtaWNoLmVkdS8/cD0xNzc2PjsgcmVsPXNob3J0bGluaw== causes the error listed above.

   ```
        This is a VALID Base64 String: Go here https://www.base64decode.org/ To see. 
        CONSOLE: [14:52:45 INF] Initial String To Decode: 
        PGh0dHBzOi8vY3NlLmVuZ2luLnVtaWNoLmVkdS8%2FcD0xNzc2PjsgcmVsPXNob3J0bGluaw==
        CONSOLE: [14:52:45 INF] UrlDecode String: 
        PGh0dHBzOi8vY3NlLmVuZ2luLnVtaWNoLmVkdS8/cD0xNzc2PjsgcmVsPXNob3J0bGluaw==
        CONSOLE: [14:52:45 INF] UrlDecode String: #72
        CONSOLE: [14:52:45 ERR] Exception: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at FreeThreatFeedLibrary.Helper.ExtensionMethods.SmartDecode(String value)
   ```
5. I use the encode-decode function like this in my view

   ```
   <a href="/ipaddress/pivotSearch/@PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString()/@content.SmartEncode()/1" target="_blank"> TEST </a>
   ```

The following content fails to SmartEncode Successfully:

1. 1B7AE3AAF003CA8A23ACBA351CBA8084A7712F3B
2. PGh0dHBzOi8vY3NlLmVuZ2luLnVtaWNoLmVkdS8%2FcD0xNzc2PjsgcmVsPXNob3J0bGluaw==

I just don't understand what is my lack of knowledge here. I have checked sites and they seem to such as https://www.base64decode.org/ and they seem to decode.  Why?!!?

Update:  Based on the Answers I am trying to use the Url.Action to generate the data to pass.  As reflected below: my path is hard-coded with a pre-amble string of /ipaddress/pivotsearch/ <-- then the ambient values are placed. When i use the code below, the /<-- are escaped.

:

```
                                                        <a href=@Url.Action(@PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString(), "/ipaddress/pivotSearch/", new {
                                                            key= @PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString(),
                                                            value = @content
                                           })"> Test </a>
```

Comment: Your "smart" encoding/decoding methods are too smart. Don't do URL encoding there. I suggest using `Url.Action` and passing route values to build the URL.

Comment: @madreflecton: Do you know how to supply a Url.Action with a named route (as listed above?)

Comment: *PGh...aw==* - that string has 74 characters including the padding "==", so that's invalid. It doesn't need padding. *1B7AE3AAF...* - that's hex, not base64. A hex string is technically valid Base64, just doesn't make sense and doesn't return the right content. And Base64decode.org is a very tolerant decoder, which can't be said about `Convert.FromBase64String()`

Comment: It's not a "named route" because you don't have a *route name* specified. You have the route (path) itself. And it's the same as you would any other, specifying the `name`, `value`, and optionally `incomingPage` properties in the `routeValues` argument (whether that's an anonymous object or dictionary, doesn't matter). There's nothing special about it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#url-generation-and-ambient-values

Comment: @madreflection:   When using Url.Action with a "supplied path" results in encoded values:

Comment: :

                                                            <a href=@Url.Action(@PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString(), "/ipaddress/pivotSearch/", new {
                                                                key= @PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString(),
                                                                value = @content
                                               })"> Test </a>

Comment: You don't specify "/ipaddress/pivotSearch/" when using `Url.Action`. You specify "pivotSearch" for the `action` parameter (and the controller name in the `controller` parameter if you're coming from a diffrent controller). Routing is an abstraction of paths. You're trying to ignore the abstraction. You have to lean into it.

Comment: Also, you don't need `@` within the anonymous object. The only time you need to do that is when you need to specify `"@class` because "class" is a keyword. The extra `@` symbols are noise.

Comment: @madreflection:   When using the controller and action, it results in the incorrect route IE: "  GET http://localhost:5000/PivotSearchController/pivotSearch? "    This should match my current route of what i defined ABOVE?   <a href=@Url.Action("pivotSearch", "PivotSearchController", new {
                                                                key= @PivotSearchKeyEnum.BANNER_VALUE.ToString(),
                                                                value = content
                                               })"> Test </a>
 <-- Results in a route

Comment: First, don't include "Controller" in the controller name. This is MVC 101. Second, if you're expecting the path to be "/ipaddress/pivotSearch", then there's no way "PivotSearch" would be the controller name unless PivotSearchController has some unexpected Route attributes overriding it. It would be something like "ipaddress", and the class it's in would be `ipaddressController`.

Comment: Fixed it.  So people don't make the same mistake.

Comment: @madreflection: Thank you so very much. Your method worked, and you were right, my smart method is actually just bad.  Thank you for your time spent, and I hope something wonderful happens for you friend.